# Is it possible to save an Entire Project created via the console on Google Cloud Platform and restore it later?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a project created via the console.  The project is on hold and might be revived in 6 months.  I would like to download to local storage, delete it, then upload it to the cloud if/when the project is taken off hold.  I have not been able to get gsutil working on my machine. (Newbie to the SDK)

I know how to delete the project "Shutdown", I have saved parts (i.e. MySQL Database, Cloud Functions, etc.).  but I can't figure out how to save the project with it's users, permissions, settings, intact.

Is there a way?  (I am concerned about costs while it is not used, otherwise I would leave it.)

Comment: Searching both internally and externally, there seem to be no way to "download" a project to a local storage.                                                                                                  
However, if a project is shutdown, it can be recovered in [30 days](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects).

Comment: Did you actually calculate the costs to keep the project and resources versus the time to save everything, document what you have and the time to restore/rebuild? There is no supported way to "download" a project for later retrieval. Each service has its own supported features for backup and restore. In some cases, such as Cloud Storage, it may be cheaper to keep the data online than paying the cost to download and then reupload.

Comment: I don't know enough to "calculate the cost".  But I am leaving it place right now and trying to figure out what the cost is.  So far, it looks like zero, but I'm not sure.  Some stuff may only show up once a month.   And from what I can tell, there is no way to easily download/upload.